# PHP array comparison

Tags: php, arrays

How to compare 2 arrays with each other?
For example i have `array("a", "b", "c")` and `array("a", "c", "b")` It would return true when they're compared. But if one of the letters if not found in one of them it would return false. Order is not important.

Comment: can it be something as simple as if (serialize(sort($array1)) == serialize(sort($array2))?

Comment: @Alec: `sort` does not return the array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to bring the content of both arrays into the same order prior to comparison:

```
sort($array1);
sort($array2);
// now you can compare as usual
if ($array1 == $array2) ...
```

Or use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) if you want to maintain keys.

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
if (empty(array_diff($array1, $array2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This would not work anyway, array_diff only returns entities from array1 that are missing from array2.  You would also need to check `array_diff($array2, $array1)` for completeness.

Comment: @soulmerge, now `empty` works on expressions since PHP 5.5.0 at least.