# Array values comparison regardless of their position and get the count of matched values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare two arrays and want to get the number of values matched in PHP. e.g

```
$a1 = array(one, two, three);
$a2 = array(two, one, three);
```

If i compare these arrays i should get `0` difference as result. Can anybody help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to get the count of the matched values regardless of position shouldn't your example return `3` since they all match?  Question confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$arr2 = array('two', 'one', 'three');
echo "number of differences : " . count(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
$a2 = array( 2 , 1, 3, 8 );
$matched = array_intersect( $a1, $a2 );
var_dump( $matched );
```

this should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

array_intersect will give you all the elements or the first array that exist in the second - using the keys of the first array

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
$diff = count(array_diff($a1, $a2));
$matches = count($a1) - $diff;
```

Refer: [PHP array comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541080/php-array-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

i made an simple function for you

This function will give you the repeated and unrepeated data

i used contries as example

```
$contries1=array('egypt','america','england');
$contires2=array('egypt','england','china');
function countryRepeated($contries1,$contires2,$status='1'){
    foreach($contries1 as $country){
        if(in_array($country,$contires2))
            $repeated[]=$country;
        else
            $unrepeated[]=$country;
    }
        return ($status=='1')?$repeated:$unrepeated;
}
```

To get the repeated contries use

```
print_r(countryRepeated($contries1,$contires2));
```

**Results:**

```
Array ( [0] => egypt [1] => england )
```

Or if you would like to get the unreapeated contries

**You can use:**

```
print_r(countryRepeated($contries1,$contires2,'2'));
```

**Results:**

```
Array ( [0] => america )
```